# EditText sometimes randomly not showing?

Tags: android

So I have an app that has this EditText. With some devices (generally the ones with higher resolutions), the EditText tends to randomly not show. However, it can be solved by restarting the app.

Here's a picture of how it should be:

[image: How it should be]

And here's a picture of how it sometimes it randomly disappears:

[image: Disappeared]

It is important to clarify that the disappearing doesn't happen while the app is running, when you open the app, the editText is either there or not.

Thank you so much!

This is the XML for the EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/abs"
    android:editable="true"
    android:numeric="decimal"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn" />
```

Comment: Can you share your XML with us?

Comment: Can you share it in the question and format is using code blocks?

Comment: Sure, no problem, just a second. Edit: done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

The above line mean `EditText` will have same `width` as the size of text inside it. When `EditText` is empty it will be so small that you can't see.

You can fix this making `EditText` width same as its parent

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

or you can fix width by providing your own width:

```
android:layout_width="80dp"
```

Comment: Right, I will try that, but why is it sometimes showing and sometimes not?

Comment: It depends on your complete Activity layout.

Comment: Oh right I think I got it know, thank you for the response, it did solve the issue!